# Copying MySQL table data to another table

Tags: mysql

I want to copy the data from one MySQL table to another table. The source table contains 30 million records. the SQL connection gets lost when I tried to copy the data using the SQL query

```
INSERT table2 SELECT * FROM table1
```

Is there any external tool avaliable to do this job from the shell

Thanks

Sree

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql` command line tool should be able to handle this just fine.